# How to decompose pauli operator into the product of stabilizers in stim?

Tags: stim

In stim, is there an easy method to decompose a Pauli operator into a product of stabilizers in the group $\langle S \rangle$? I can achieve this by performing Gauss-Jordan elimination manually, but I wonder whether there is a more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by using [`stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers) and [`stim.Tableau.inverse`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.inverse) and [`stim.Tableau.__call__(stim.PauliString)`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.__call__):

```python
from typing import List, Tuple

import stim

def decompose_pauli_string(
    pauli_string: stim.PauliString,
    basis: List[stim.PauliString],
) -> Tuple[int, List[int]]:
    # Decompose into the basis by inverting its tableau.
    tableau = stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers(
        basis,
        allow_redundant=False,
        allow_underconstrained=True,
    )
    inv = tableau.inverse()
    out_paulis = inv(pauli_string)

    # Extract signs and used indices.
    out_used_indices = []
    for q, p in enumerate(out_paulis):
        if p != 0 and q >= len(basis):
            raise ValueError("pauli_string not in span of basis")
        if p == 1 or p == 2:
            raise ValueError("pauli_string anti-commutes with basis")
        if p == 3:
            out_used_indices.append(q)
    assert out_paulis.sign in [-1, +1]

    return int(out_paulis.sign.real), out_used_indices
```

Example:

```python
target = stim.PauliString("XXX")
basis = [
    stim.PauliString("XYY"),
    stim.PauliString("ZZ_"),
    stim.PauliString("_ZZ"),
]
sign, indices = decompose_pauli_string(target, basis)
assert indices == [0, 2]
reconstructed = stim.PauliString(len(target)) * sign
for k in indices:
    reconstructed *= basis[k]
assert reconstructed == target
```

You may wish to store the inverse instead of recomputing it every time, if you're going to be using this method a lot. That way the costs will be $O(n^2)$ per decomposition instead of $O(n^3)$ per decomposition. If you don't care about the sign of the result, you can also get $O(n^2)$ cost per decomposition by using `tableau.inverse(unsigned=True)` instead of `tableau.inverse()`.